# Rapidly increasing memory due to load url in UIWebview ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, ios7, uiwebview

I am loading URL in UIWebview and it is working fine.But during loading of web request it is consuming memory too much.Whenever i load some URL in UIWebview memory is increased from 30mb to 95mb and based on each link clicked in UIWebview it is still increasing and reach to 180mb and so on.I used some code to remove memoryin UIWebview.But there is no benefit.I have done memory management by Analyze in Xcode but there are no leaks and i also check allocations and leaks.It is just creating one instance of UIWebview.

This is my code:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {   
    int cacheSizeMemory = 4*1024*1024; // 4MB
    int cacheSizeDisk = 32*1024*1024; // 32MB
    NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"] autorelease];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
 }

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
 {
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
 }
```

**ViewController.h**

@property(nonatomic,strong)UIWebview *webview;

**ViewController.m**
    @synthesize webview;

```
-(void)viewdidLoad
{
    NSString *urlString = @"some url";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webview=[uiwebview alloc]init];
    [self.webview loadRequest:request];
}
```

/*webview delegates

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(Bool)animated
{
   self.webview=nil;
 [self.webview removefromSuperView]
 [self.webview loadHtmlString:@"" baseUrl:nil]
  [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:NSURLRequest];
  [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
  for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) 
  {

      if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:someNSStringUrlDomain]) {

       [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
  }
}
```

I am facing this issue for few days.Please give me some alternative or method to remove UIWebviewmemory.

Answer (score 0):

In `viewWillDisapear` You are setting your `WebView` reference to `nil` so the removing in the next line fails.

Try setting your reference to nil after you completed all cleanup around the `WebView`, i.e. in the last line of the method.

You probably also need to remove the delegate of the `WebView` (before nilling).

Comment: Still the memory is leaking.The memory is still same after removing the delegate of UIWebview.

Comment: please post your adjusted code, so we can see potential remaining errors

Answer (score 0):

**As dogsgod** is pointed out the way OP release memory is not proper, but
there are other things which should mention for this type of question.

- If you are developing new application I suggest you to use [ARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting) for your project
- If its not possible to implement [ARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting) then follow below advice

In `viewdidLoad()` you are allocating object that's good but its better if you first check that is object is already allocated of not (as it may change that it is allocated before pushing it into navigation).
**Sample Code**

```
if(self.webview!=nil)
{
self.webview = nil; // release memory
}

// Code for allocating memory.
```

If you alloc object in `viewDidLoad()` then must be deallco in `dealloc()` method.

**NOTE:**
When you assign any object nil, it means now object is not point to the old location and you have no control over that object, so calling some method like `[self.webview removefromSuperView]` after assigning nil to webview it have **`no effect`**.

---

**Extra note:**
Please read this [document](http://stablekernel.com/blog/uiviewcontroller-best-practices-viewwillappear-or-viewdidload/) for knowledge about methods like viewDidload,viewWillAppear ... etc.

Comment: I tried whatever you said but still memory is increasing.

Comment: Can you share sample project ?

Comment: Hey i solved this problem,i used WkWebview instead of UIWebview.It is consuming low memory.